# How can I remove spurious line on zoomable sunburst?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

If you look at the [zoomable sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373):

[image]

...and if you change the background color of the `<svg>` element, then when you zoom in, you'll notice the stroke continues up to the top of the SVG element, beyond the arc(s) of the sunburst. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TNBh.png) is an example - note the extra line going up from the top of the circle.

[image]

You don't see this on the demos, because the background is white and the stroke is white. But I've got much stronger contrast between the stroke and background colors, so this spurious line jars.

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine for me on Chrome 33.  I know some browsers have issues with zoom so this might be something browser-specific.

Comment: I get this on Chrome 33, Chrome 34 beta, Firefox 27, Safari 6.1.2, IE9, and IE10. Have you changed the background color of the SVG element? The demos look fine for me "out of the box", but not if you change the background color, eg to #ccc.

Comment: Yeah, I used the Chrome web tools to change the background-color of the SVG to black and it looks fine at all zoom levels I tried.  I was doing this on the mbostock example itself but the image you posted looks like it is from different code.  It also looks like there is a yellow circle that is bigger than the chart area and the line you're describing goes to the edge of that.  Seems like maybe this is something specific to your implementation?

Comment: I've changed the example screenshot: using Chrome I edited the background color of SVG directly on the example, then zoomed in.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, running MacOSX 10.8.5

Comment: I just tried it on a Mac (also 10.8.5) and I don't see it in the main example using Chrome.

Comment: @ScottCameron, are you zooming in on one of the categories that doesn't have the full depth -- because it's there!

Comment: Ha, my mistake.  I was using browser zoom (CTRL-+) not the sunburst zoom navigation.  That was dumb. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that when you zoom in on one segment, the segments that aren't children of it get folded down to zero angle.  But they are still drawn, and they are still stroked in white.  It's easy to overlook because (a) the white stroke matches the white background, and (b) any adjacent arcs are drawn overtop.  But if the background isn't white and the displayed arcs don't cover up the full depth, you're left with this spike from the folded-up arcs.

The solution is therefore to actually hide any arcs that aren't part of this zoom level after animating their transition to zero width:

```
function click(d) {
  path.attr("opacity", 1) //turn on visibility so you can see animation
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attrTween("d", arcTween(d)) 
         //this creates a tween for *all* elements based on the clicked element's data
         //when the transition comletes, the domain of the x scale will be the 
         //extent of this element and all its children
      .transition().duration(0)
          //create a zero-length transition that will start
          //after the shape transition completes
      .style("opacity", function(d2,i2) {
            return ((d2.x >= d.x + d.dx) || (d2.x + d2.dx <= d.x) )?
               //is this data outside of the domain?
                   0 : //yes - zero opacity (transparent)
                   1; //no - full opacity (visible)
      });
}
```

Fiddle showing the original problem: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ekL8z/

Fiddle corrected with the code above: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ekL8z/1/

Alternate code with the opacity transitioning instead of changing at the beginning and end:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ekL8z/2/
(My original code for setting opacity was based on the final value of the x domain, and so couldn't run until the first transition was complete, but by using the data values directly the two transitions can be simultaneous, it is just a matter of which appearance you prefer.)

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but the code doesn't fix the problem :-) I grabbed the demo and changed the click() function as above, but I'm still getting the spike. I don't grok d3 enough to work out what's wrong, but I notice that the outer function (click) has a 'd' argument, as does the function passed to opacity. Are all those 'd's referring to the right d?

Comment: That's a good point, but not the problem.  The `d` in the inside function over-rides the outside `d`, but I suspect the problem is that the code is running before the final value of the x domain is set.  I'll edit it with a different way of doing the calculation using the two data objects.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I went with your alternate code - feels smoothest.